# null DateTime from excel sheet adding to database using C#

Tags: c#, excel, datetime

I am having an issue with getting a value to pass into this variable. It is null coming from the excel file (using Aspose) but a DateTime doesn't except it. I added the **DateTime ?** to the variable but that doesn't help. I have tried a few ways that I know but none of them are working for the incoming null value. If the value is null, it has to stay null which the database allows for a null value. Can someone help me get this to work? Is there an easier way to go about this?

Try 1

```
EnterDate = Convert.ToDateTime(dr["EnterDate"]);
EnterDate = (EnterDate.HasValue) ? EnterDate : DateTime.Now;
```

Try 2

```
RepealedDate = (dr["RepealedDate"] == null) ? (DateTime?)null : Convert.ToDateTime(dr["RepealedDate"]);
```

Answer (score 1):

Replace your second try with this:

```
DateTime? repealedDate = (dr["RepealedDate"] == null) ? 
    null : Convert.ToDateTime(dr["RepealedDate"]);
```

You can't cast null to `DateTime?` to solve the problem, you have to define the variable as being of type `DateTime?`.

Comment: Error from compiler: Type of conditional expression cannot be determined because there is no implicit conversion between '<null>' and 'System.DateTime' - How can this be addressed?

Comment: @Katherine What is the type of `dr["RepealedDate"]`? Is that `Datetime?` too? If so, does `Convert.ToDateTime((DateTime)dr["RepealedDate"]);` fix the problem?

Comment: This is the current format from Excel (dd-mmm-yy) for the date cells. With that inserted in, it still errors out.

Comment: Does it error with the same message or are you getting a new one?

Comment: @Katherine Sorry, but I'm a bit confused by your comment. Are you saying the null problem is resolved and you have a new problem, or is this an additional one? AFAIK the .NET DataTime struct should understand dd-mmm-yy as a date, even with the US local, but probably not if you are using a non-English local. Could you supply more details if possible please?

Comment: It kept throwing the same error. It wasn't accepting the null values coming from the excel spreadsheet. I found a solution for this using 'DateTime dt; if (DateTime.TryParse(dr["EnactedDate"].ToString(), out dt)) EnactedDate = dt;  else EnactedDate = null;'

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't find a good solution on web. So I tried to handle it myself.
I took data as string from `Excel Sheet` and then I controlled if its empty or not. If its I set it to `null` else I converted it to DateTime as below. This avoids me from exception that can happen in `Convert` function.

```
StartDate = dr[2].ToString().Trim();

if (StartDate != "")
   r.Data.StartDate = Convert.ToDateTime(StartDate);
else
   r.Data.StartDate = null;
```